# I can't update my user session in next-auth

Tags: javascript, next.js, jwt, fetch-api, next-auth

I want when the user enters a specific page to fetch the data from the API and set the new data to the new user and render it, but I can't make it work, I'm using Next 14 and app router. This is my code:

```
 session: {
    // Use JWT for session strategy
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, trigger }) {
      if (user) {
        // Assign user data to token on initial sign-in
        token.email = user.email;
        token.telNo = user.telNo;
        token.remaining_messages = user.remaining_messages;
        token.isCancelled = user.isCancelled;
        token.customerId = user.customerId;
        token.currentPlan = user.currentPlan;
        token.planExpiryDate = user.planExpiryDate;
        token.loginToken = user.loginToken;
      } else if (trigger === "jwt") {
        try {
          const res = await fetch("api/user", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({ token: token.loginToken }),
          });

          if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Failed to fetch user data: ${res.statusText}`);
          }

          const data = await res.json();

          // Update token with new user data
          token.email = data.email;
          token.telNo = data.telNo;
          token.remaining_messages = data.remaining_messages;
          token.isCancelled = data.isCancelled;
          token.customerId = data.customerId;
          token.currentPlan = data.currentPlan;
          token.planExpiryDate = data.planExpiryDate;
          // Keep the loginToken as it is
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error updating the JWT:", error);
        }
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      // Update session with data from token
      session.user = {
        email: token.email,
        name: token.loginToken, // If 'name' is not relevant, consider removing or adjusting
        telNo: token.telNo,
        remaining_messages: token.remaining_messages,
        isCancelled: token.isCancelled,
        customerId: token.customerId,
        currentPlan: token.currentPlan,
        planExpiryDate: token.planExpiryDate,
        loginToken: token.loginToken,
      };
      return session;
    },
  },
```

I will be posting my update  code in comments

Comment: this my code in   `const [hasFetched, setHasFetched] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasFetched && session) {
      update();
      setHasFetched(true);
    }
  }, []);`

Comment: Please EDIT your question to add clarity not add comments with code